# what are hasOwnProperty and push for in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Weeks ago, I bought a tutorial book about chatting application with angularjs. Actually, this book is give information about angularjs and some other information, but the chatting application itself is not explained, the writer just give all the code to build it without the explanation. so, I just copy and paste the code, but I dont understand some code in there. like this function for send message:

```
 $scope.messageshistory = {};
    $scope.tmp = {};

    // send message
    $scope.sendMessage = function(){
        $scope.messages = {
            from      : $scope.datauser['data']['_id'],
            fromname  : $scope.datauser['data']['nama'],
            to        : $scope.tmpuserid,
            message   : $scope.tmp['sendmessage'],
            time      : moment()
        };
          //event emit message
        socket.emit('message',$scope.messages,function(callback){       
          if(!callback['error']){
          $scope.messages['time'] = moment($scope.messages['time']).format('DD-MMMM-YYYY hh:mm');

           if ($scope.messageshistory.hasOwnProperty($scope.tmpuserid)){ $scope.messageshistory[$scope.tmpuserid].push($scope.messages);
                }else{
                    $scope.messageshistory[$scope.tmpuserid] =   [];
                    $scope.messageshistory[$scope.tmpuserid].push($scope.messages);
                }
                $scope.tmp['sendmessage'] = '';
          }else{
               var msg = callback['error'];
                navigator.notification.alert(msg,'','Error Report', 'Ok');
            }

            $scope.$apply();
        });
    };
```

my question is what is `$scope.messageshistory.hasOwnProperty($scope.tmpuserid)` actually for? and what is `$scope.messageshistory[$scope.tmpuserid].push($scope.messages)`doing? thanks for your explanation

Comment: These are plain JavaScript methods, they have nothing to do with Angular. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara can you give an explanation in my case? what actually those codes do in this function?

Comment: As said above, they are JS methods. Read the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$scope.messageshistory` is an associative array of messages history by user id. `$scope.messageshistory.hasOwnProperty($scope.tmpuserid)` checks if user has a messages history with tempuserid. in case he did, `$scope.messageshistory[$scope.tmpuserid].push($scope.messages)` pushes the message to the array that represents the message history between current user and tempuserid.

Comment: thank that explained a lot. but how about in `else`? what is []?

Comment: It creates a new array since there is no messages history for tempuserid and then it pushes the message to this array

Comment: so, if I delete the `if` and `else` and just use the `push` is correct too because basiclly it will push all the messages with/without the `hasownproperty`?